# How to get a link to a file from a VSO repo

Tags: azure-devops

When I browse a GitHub repo, I can copy the URL from the browser, and I can share it like this - 
https://github.com/zlatko-michailov/onesql/blob/master/lang/src/onesql.syntax.ts. The file content is returned in the http response stream without any decorations.

How can I do the same thing for a VSO repo? If I have to tweak the URL a little bit, that's OK.

I see the browser uses a REST API that is documented here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0. I played with different combinations of `includeContent`, `$format`, `download`, etc., but I could only get the content as a separate download, not in the http response body.

The subject file is some CSV data, and the client is Excel, which doesn't seem to be able to handle downloads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a link to raw content of file in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-link-to-raw-content-of-file-in-azure-devops)

Comment: Why is that thread marked as resolved? The response doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved my own problem. There is no need to create a feed.

The API that fetches raw files is `sourceProviders`. The link is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/source%20providers/get%20file%20contents?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

It is not very well documented - examples for the required parameters are missing. The tricky one is `sourceProvider`. It has to be `tfsgit`. Skipping `serviceEndpointId` worked for me.

Here is the pattern:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/sourceProviders/tfsgit/filecontents?&repository={repository}&commitOrBranch={commitOrBranch}&path={path}&api-version=5.0-preview.1
```