# Is there a way to (perma)link source code snippets in Azure DevOps wiki pages?

Tags: azure-devops, markdown, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

You know.., something similar like [Github (that other Microsoft product) permalinks](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet)?
I've tried using `<iframe>` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops)) but it seems that only work for videos?

Using the [REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-link-to-raw-content-of-file-in-azure-devops) I can link to a file directly but I want to the contents to be visible in the Wiki markdown pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looing for it's not available in Azure DevOps right now.

There used to be a Permalinks  related user voice. [Add Permalinks in Wiki](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365921/add-permalinks-in-wiki.html) But it's not talking about the same thing.

You could raise up a feature request in [Develop Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea)  page.